# converting Excel VBA from InternetExplorerMedium to MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I created a macro using `InternetExplorerMedium` however due to IE being unstable and throwing errors ad hoc I want to change this to use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`

I have been successful in changing the specific parts of code thus far however I have come across a part where I am struggling. This part of code however I am getting an error `runtime error 91` at:

```
Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument ' <----- error debug here
```

How do I overcome this?

Snippets of code below relating to this query:

```
Sub TPMRebatePayment()


    Dim IE As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim frame As HTMLFrameElement
    Dim myurl As String


<snip code>

    'Opens IE

    myurl = "http://crmprdas02.aunz.lncorp.net:8011/sap(bD1lbiZjPTEwMCZkPW1pbg==)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_bsp_frame/entrypoint.do?appl=crmd_stlmt_rb&version=0&blview=znfl_stl&crm_bsp_restore=false"
    IE.Open "GET", myurl, False
    IE.Send


    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    'Loops thru entering payments
    LastRow = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Recalc last row as data has been entered

    For iRow = 3 To LastRow
        If SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & iRow) <> "" Then
            Set HTMLdoc = New HTMLDocument
            Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("crmA")(0)

            ''' This is where the error occurs                
            Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__simpleSearch__as_button").Click   'Click Search Button
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__advancedSearch_advancedSearch_REBATE_NO").Value = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & iRow).Value    'Enter Accrual into Rebate No. Field
            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__advancedSearch__sm_go").Click
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SRES2_BUT_GOTO").Click      'Click Go To Button
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
            HTMLdoc.getElementById("EDIT_DETAILS").Click        'Then Details to enter the payment page
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            AccBal = HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZACCRUED_SC").Value       'Scrapes accrual balance

            If AccBal <> 0 Then
                If Right(AccBal, 1) = "-" Then                                                          'Converts to number
                    SourceShtTPM.Range("E" & iRow).Value = "-" & Left(AccBal, Len(AccBal) - 1)
                    Else: SourceShtTPM.Range("E" & iRow).Value = "-" & AccBal
                End If

                If SourceShtTPM.Range("H" & iRow).Value > 0 Then       'Confirms if enough money to pay
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZAMOUNT").Value = Round(SourceShtTPM.Range("H" & iRow).Value, 2)   'Enters "Amount to be Paid"
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZCLAIMNO_SC").Value = SourceShtCLM.Range("A2").Value       'Enters claim no.
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_BUT_ZST_CPY_RT").Click     'Click button to distribute
                    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("ZCR_COPY_TO_SKU_RATE").Click            'distributes to sku
                    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_BUT_ZSTL_COPY").Click      'Click button to distribute
                    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("ZCR_COPY_TO_SKU_AMNT").Click            'distributes to sku
                    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                    HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_ZSTL_PART_SETTLE").Click   'Clicks Pay Claim
                    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                    'The line below will save the rebate payment.
                    'DO NOT CHANGE UNLESS CODE IS 100%
                    'HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_ZCR_STLMT_SAVE").Click    'Clicks Save
                    'While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

                    SourceShtTPM.Range("C" & iRow) = Split(IE.document.getElementsByName("crmA")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("APLG0_lnk").innerText, Chr$(32))(3)

                    'Col "Y" = entered commentary
                    SourceShtTPM.Range("D" & iRow).Value = "Claim Paid"
                Else
                    'Col "Y" = payment amount to enter
                    SourceShtTPM.Range("D" & iRow).Value = "Not Paid"
                End If
            Else
                SourceShtTPM.Range("D" & iRow).Value = "No money in accrual"
            End If

        IE.navigate "http://crmprdas02.aunz.lncorp.net:8011/sap(bD1lbiZjPTEwMCZkPW1pbg==)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_bsp_frame/entrypoint.do?appl=crmd_stlmt_rb&version=0&blview=znfl_stl&crm_bsp_restore=false"
        While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing

        End If

    Next iRow


   IE.Quit

   <snip code>

End Sub
```

Comment: You create HTMLdoc then read from it, but it has no contents & is empty.  The error is likely because frame is Nothing.  You need to assign the downloaded HTML text to the document, something like HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = htmlText

Comment: yep, you are right, I hovered over `frame` and is `= nothing`. How and where do I incorporate `HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = htmlText` into the code?

Comment: I used `HTMLdoc.Body.innerText = IE.responseText` after `Set HTMLdoc = New HTMLDocument` and debug.print outputs the page

Comment: That link doesn't work in the browser for me.  It looks internal.

Comment: Hi @qharr yes its internal.. i will test shortly and revert back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the while wend loop. Read the XMLHTTP response into an html document object. I usually decode en route.

```
Dim sresponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, myUrl
myUrl = "abc.com"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", myUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
   sresponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With

Set html = New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = sresponse
```

Then test the contents to see if frame present and contains info.

Comment: errors at `html.Body.innerHTML = sresponse` `Run-time error '601' Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: Have you examined sresponse?

Comment: `Debug.Print sresponse` produces some text.. has <html> some text </html>

Comment: Apologise for the late 'tick' The issue I was having is that CRM and my upgraded SAP are not compatible and thus this code wasn't working. After understanding this and testing the above it works. Thanks for th help and again sorry for the delay.